# SourceMapping Application Code in Karma and Webpack

Tags: webpack, source-maps, karma-mocha

It's an Angular 1.x app, we are using Webpack for packaging and Karma for testing. We use "inline-source-map" as our devTool and it's working well when we serve the application. In our Karma Config, we use "[Karma-sourcemap-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sourcemap-loader)" plugin and we see our original format our test code in chrome dev tools, but the application code itself is not readable.

This is the relevant sections in our KarmaConfig

```
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['mocha'],
preprocessors: {
  'test/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
  'app/scripts/**/*.js': ['coverage']
},
files: [
  '*/build-plugin/polyfills/*.js'
],
webpack: webpackTestConfig,
```

and this is the relevant section webpack config.

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    _: "underscore",
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    this: {}
  }),
  new BowerWebpackPlugin({
    searchResolveModulesDirectories: false
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    minimize: true
  })
],
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Isparta loader. We changed our karma entry-point to be a single file instead of the glob pattern.

https://github.com/deepsweet/isparta-loader/issues/1